# Execute object files from different directories using Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have the following Makefile entry:

```
TEST_DIRS = abcd pqr xyz

test_lib :
        for dir in $(TEST_DIRS); do \
                $(MAKE) -C $$dir; \
        done
run :
        ./abcd/test/abcd_test.o --log_level=message
        ./pqr/test/pqr_test.o --log_level=message
        ./xyz/test/xyz_parser_test.o --log_level=message

test :  test_lib run
```

I don't want to write 3 separate commands for run target instead make it generic. So that everytime a new test file gets added, I dont want add a new command under run target. Can somebody help me?

Comment: I don't think those are object files.

Comment: You generally execute binaries not object files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TESTS := $(addprefix TEST_, $(TEST_DIRS))

run: $(TESTS)

TEST_%:
    ./$*/test/$*_test.o --log_level=message
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the naming scheme is consistent (and those are just oddly named binaries and not actually object files) then something like this should work:

Using a shell loop:

```
run :
        for name in $(TEST_DIRS); do \
            ./$$name/test/$${name}_test.o --log_level=message; \
        done
```

Using make `foreach`:

```
run :
        $(foreach name,$(TEST_DIRS),./$(name)/test/$(name)_test.o --log_level=message;)
```